# How do you add paths to libraries for cmake when using the ninja generator and the LLVM compilers?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, ninja, linker-flags

My main goal is to use cmake with the ninja generator to build a C++ project with the LLVM clang compiler.

I am trying to get two libraries linked so when cmake tests the compilers, the compilers will be able to find the libraries.

I am consistently getting

```
lld-link: error: could not open 'oldnames.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'msvcrtd.lib': no such file or directory
```

when these files exist.

Cmake is able to find the libraries as this runs fine

```
# Find the required libraries
find_library(OLDNAMES_LIB oldnames.lib)
find_library(MSVCRD_LIB msvcrtd.lib)

if (NOT OLDNAMES_LIB)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to find oldnames.lib")
endif()

if (NOT MSVCRD_LIB)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to find msvcrtd.lib")
endif()
```

I have tried setting linker flags several ways and it is clear from the output of cmake that the library flags are NOT being passed to the C compiler when ninja invokes it.

I tried this

```
target_link_libraries(sound_sculptor_test PRIVATE \"${MSVCRD_LIB}\" \"${OLDNAMES_LIB}\")
```

and this

```
target_link_options(sound_sculptor_test PRIVATE "-L\"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/lib/onecore/x64/\"")
```

and this

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OLDNAMES_LIB} ${MSVCRD_LIB}")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OLDNAMES_LIB} ${MSVCRD_LIB}")
```

I have also set the CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS to "-L"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/lib/onecore/x64/"", but oldnames.lib is still not found even though it is in that folder.

CMake is 3.26.4
Make is 4.4.1
Ninja is 1.11.1
LLVM is 16.0.6

I have wasted a ridiculous amount of time trying to get this to work.

Turns out I just had to delete the cmakecache after creating the CFLAGS environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

Setting CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS to "-L"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/lib/onecore/x64/"" allowed the libraries to be found.